# Чтение базы данных из файла

Tags: c++, qt

Пишу программу на плюсах в QT

У меня есть файл .txt, в нем лежит база данных типа:

```
Name Adress Data Manage
Name Adress Data Manage  
Name Adress Data Manage  
Name Adress Data Manage
```

Name, Adress, Data и Manage - это структура, которую мне необходимо засунуть в `std::vector<struct> vec`

Вопрос: как считать эту базу данных и каждому члену структуры присвоить значение из файла?

Comment: какой код есть на текущий момент?

Comment: Есть функция, которая принимает ссылку на файл:

`void DataBase::loadFromFile(const QString &path)`


И объявленный вектор, в котором пока ничего нет. `Vector<struct> vec`